# Error while calling next activity in android?

Tags: android

this is my first activity code:

```
public class hello extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // Perform action on click
            Intent i = new Intent(hello.this,Selectmsg.class);

            startActivity(i);           
        }
    });
  }
}
```

following is my next activity code:

```
public class Selectmsg extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

    }
}
```

but i am occurring error.it closing forcefully.,its not working.i just want to call next activity.and i also written driver for next activity in Androidmanifest.so please help me to remove error..
Thanks in Advance--

Comment: Please post the logcat output

Comment: What is the exception that is being thrown? (the one in the logs, not the generic "Force Close")

Comment: Ensure you have declared your second activity in your Android Manifest file or your app will throw an `ActivityNotFound` exception

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{demo.hello/demo.hello.hello}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
this is the error in logcat...

Comment: @Rivi i have declared in Android Manifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{demo.hello/demo.hello.hello}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
```

I believe therefore that you should change this line:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

To this:

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

Comment: No worries - we all make them, and it's sometimes difficult to see the problem when you've been looking at the same code for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setClassName("packageName","Classname");
startActivity(i);
```